# custom component toolbar fragment with onOptionmenu items

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, toolbar

I am stuck simple issue and i know i am doing something minor wrong , My issue is when i am using set Toolbar in MainActivity and after when i am trying to add optionMenu in fragment at a time my toolBar's child component(RelativeLayout in my case) size changed..

Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/button_blue"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/zenith"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/adminhome_cust_titleimage"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/small_app_logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include layout="@layout/content_admin_main" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin_home, container, false);
        utils = new Utils(getActivity());
        calendarView = (CompactCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.admin_compactcalendar_view);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.admin_toolbar);
}
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.adminhome_profilelogo, menu);
}
```

How can i set my imageView in proper center of toolas you can see in first image..

Comment: Make adminhome_cust_titleimage toRightOf admin_toolbar_icon and alignParentRight true

Comment: yes i tried with rightOf but center image sticked to left drawer image..

Comment: Try removing TextView from toolbar relativeLayout

Comment: no still not working @FerdousAhamed

Comment: Instead of using option menu you can add an extra imageView to toolbar relativeLayout with aligned right for your profile option.

Comment: without adding to ImageView to toolBar child layout can we achieve this thing ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/adminhome_cust_titleimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/admin_toolbar_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/small_app_logo" />
```

But anyway if you will add more menu elements your icon will be centered from end of home button and start of menu. Also you can remove `setHasOptionsMenu` and add one more `ImageView` in your `RelativeLayout` and your code will works.

Comment: You can check where you made a mistake by turning on in dev setting "display borders of elements"

Comment: actually i am thinking about this solution but this toolBar is set in my mainActivity so if i want to use another menuItems in other fragment so at a time how can i manage this things..

Comment: Yes, but if you are inflating menu there is additional padding for toolbar content and you cannot neglect it

Comment: okay means without adding to ImageView to toolBar child layout can we achieve this thing ?

Comment: You can write in your BaseActivity and BaseFragment logic to manage your custom menu container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143184/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-alexander-goncharenko).

Comment: For example: BaseActivity contains methods for adding/removing your custom menu container. In BaseFragment you have methods to pass layout id to be inflated and added into the menu container and method to pass there id of your menu item to handle it in your fragment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using option `menu` you can add an extra `ImageView` to Toolbar `RelativeLayout` with aligned right for your profile icon.

**Here is an example:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/admin_toolbar_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/adminhome_cust_titleimage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: yes actually i am thinking about this solution but this toolBar is set in my mainActivity so if i want to use another menuItems in other fragment so at a time how can i manage this things..